# Google Chart Tools and JSON

Tags: javascript, charts

On this example https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start The method `data.addRows()` takes a list of lists.

I have a URI (/data/mydata.json) that returns this data

```
[["Canada", 66], ["Turkey", 10], ["Hungary", 23], ["Italy", 49]]
```

Using JQuery's $.parseJSON(), I get the error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`

How do I get that data into that method in the format it wants?

UPDATE

I ran just `alert($.parseJSON('/data/mydata.json'))` and it parsed and displayed the data just fine. It seems like data.addRows() is the one throwing the error.

Here is the full code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)
function drawChart(){
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
data.addColumn('number', 'Node Count');
data.addRows($.parseJSON('/data/mydata.json'));

var options = {'title':'Tor Nodes by Country',
           'width':800,
           'height':600};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('nodes'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

Comment: Your data is just an array ....

Answer (score 0):

JQuery perfectly parses the JSON data. Output is an array of arrays.

Here is an JS example how it works:

```
var json_data = "[[\"Canada\", 66], [\"Turkey\", 10], [\"Hungary\", 23], [\"Italy\", 49]]";
var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(json_data);

document.write('<table><tr><th>City</th><th>number</th></tr>');
for (var i=0; i < parsed_data.length; i++) {
    document.write('<tr><td>' + parsed_data[i][0] + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + parsed_data[i][1] + '</td></tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
```

Are you sure that since you don't tell how you retrieve data, are you sure that JQuery didn't parsed input as a JSON when retrieving it?

[Here is a JSFiddle link to show contents of the json_data](http://jsfiddle.net/jtiai/Gjsqy/)